# MySQL - Sort certain conditions last in the result set (Unions maybe?)

Tags: mysql, resultset

I have a certain query, I need to get basically two rows with certain ids. At first I used `where id = x or id = y`. However I need to get the second parameter *last* in the result set. I came across with UNIONS, and I need to know how Unions sort results.

Will Unions help to achieve what I want?

If not, how can I achieve the desired result?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select * 
from your_table
where id in (x, y)
order by id <> x
```

or

```
order by case when id = x then 1 else 2 end
```

Comment: the second option using CASE WHEN is more efficient in processing time.

Comment: How do you know that?

Comment: the WHEN CASE sentence works in real time during the results are in memory, the other solution waits for the order after the filter is done.